# Kids with special abilities flee being sent to camps, gain friends

Tags: story-identification, books

There's this book I've been trying to find for the longest time and I just can't remember the name.

What I remember, there are these kids that have abilities or something but people see them as bad. So the main character sees that his parents want to send him to this camp-type place. So he runs away with this girl.

When they're running from the cops, they make a bus full of kids like them crash. So another joins them on the run and they go to the forest. Next thing they get to this hangar, I think where a bunch of their kind are, and they get loaded into an airplane and sent to a military surplus airbase where the entire place is full of kids and what not.

Later they get raided and get taken to these camps but are like an Auschwitz type camp. That's the last part I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Some nice detail here, but there are still things you should add if you remember them, like when you read this, what the book looked like; check out a [more complete list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit] anything else you can think of into your question.

Comment: Some of this sounds a bit like The Darkest Minds but as I haven't read it I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

It might be [Unwind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unwind_(novel)) by Neal Shusterman. It doesn’t match your description entirely but here are the **similarities:**

- 3 main characters, two boys and a girl: Connor, Risa and Lev
- The main characters are being sent to be "unwound" which involves going to an unwinding centre (sort of like a death camp)
- Connor's parents signed the unwinding papers to authorise his unwinding but Connor runs
- Risa escapes from a bus sending her to the unwinding camp (Connor has caused the bus to stop by escaping from the car carrying him).
- After escaping from the bus/cars, the three main characters hide in a forest
- There is a place in the book called "The Graveyard" which is a graveyard for old aircraft. The inhabitants (kids) live in all the old aircraft.
- There's a part in an unwinding centre which may have made you think of death camps.

**Where this might differ from your description:**

- the main characters are pretty much just powerless kids. The sci-fi element comes from the unwinding process (every bodily part is taken as an organ donation and the person is classed as "living in the divided state")
- Connor and Risa don’t start out together (but Connor  does give some consideration to asking his girlfriend to come with him when he tries to run)